# 'AXUIElementCopyAttributeValues' returns 'kAXErrorAPIDisabled'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I'm new in macOX coding, on running the following code:

```
CFArrayRef windows;
AXError result = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValues(self.elementRef, kAXWindowsAttribute, 0, 100, &windows);
```

The function returned '`kAXErrorAPIDisabled`'.

Does this mean the function is disabled? How to correct it? Many thanks.

I'm running a macOS Catalina version 10.15.7 system with latest Xcode 12

Comment: `Boolean AXAPIEnabled(void);` The user controls this using System Preferences. The APIs are disabled by default. `kAXErrorAPIDisabled` = *Assistive applications are not enabled in System Preferences.*

Comment: Got it working by setting system Accessibility permission enabled. Thanks